# Rsync overwrite files without write permission

Tags: unix, permissions, rsync

I'm trying to sync directories within the same machine, basically copying files from one directory to another directory.

under certain circumstances, the **write permission** of the destination files **will be removed** to protect them. However, rsync command seems to **ignore the lack of write permission** and overwrite all the files in the destination anyway. Any idea why?

Command used(all have the same problem):

```
$ rsync -azv --delete source/ destination/
$ rsync -azv source/ destination/
```

version:
rsync  version 2.6.9  protocol version 29

destination file permission: `-r--r--r--`, 
source file permission: `-rwxrwxrwx`,
destination file owner: same owner(not root though),
output:

```
building file list ... done

sent 101 bytes  received 26 bytes  254.00 bytes/sec
total size is 1412  speedup is 11.12
```

resulting destination file: `-rwxrwxrwx`

OS:
both macOS(latest) and redhat linux

Comment: What is the file's owner (specifically, is it the same as the user `rsync` is running as), and what are the permissions and owner on the directory the files are in?

Comment: owner of source and destination and runner of the rsync are all the same, me. The permission of destination folder is `drwxr--r--`. I changed permission of destination directory to `dr-xr-xr-x`, it still copies as usually.

Comment: I also discovered something. if permission is like `dr-xr-xr-x` for destination folder, and file is the same. it becomes a permission change operation and the destination file permission will be changed. if files are not the same, then rsync will then be blocked with this error `rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-52.200.1/rsync/main.c(996) [sender=2.6.9]`